# How to implment my async method in the right way?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I would like to know how is the best way to implement my own async method. I have read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) and it says that is not a good idea to wrapper a sync method into a task and use it as async method, because this way use other thread and use more resources, that is what we want to avoid with use async.

In the article use TaskCompletionSource, but I don't know exactly how to use it. Which is the purpose of TaskCompletionSource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best resource for writing `async` method is the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) document by Stephen Toub](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957). Much of the information in that document is now [part of the official MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

If you want a shorter (but still thorough) tutorial, I recommend my own [`async`/`await` intro blog post](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), and there are several other tutorials out there. Once you have learned a bit about `async`, the next good resource is the [official `async`/`await` FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx).

There are also tons of great `async` videos on Channel9. Many (most?) of them discuss `async` when it was still a CTP, but very few design changes were made when it went into production.

To answer your specific question, `TaskCompletionSource` is used to create a `Task` wrapper around an existing asynchronous operation (e.g., an I/O operation, timer, or event). You can't execute code in a `Task` created by `TaskCompletionSource`; you should use `Task.Run` to execute code in a `Task`.

Comment: but if I use task.Run I create a new thread and if I am not wrong, this create a new thread and it is what we want to avoid becouse use more resources and for scalability is worse. is it possible to execute code in a task without creating a new thread?

Comment: Where else is the code going to run?

Comment: True. Then if I use a code like killercam, that it was I am doinf, is the same that wrap a sync method in a task to create the async method. If this is true, in the article of my post, the autor says that this is not a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Calling a method inside another `async` method (using the .NET 5.0 `async` keyword) to me is fine. I am not sure I completely understand your question, but take the following simple example. To display the prime numbers between a starting `int` and a count we could write

```
async void DisplayPrimes()
{
    int result = await GetPrimesCountAsync(2, 10000);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

where

```
Task<int> GetPrimesCountAsync(int start, int count)
{
    return Task.Run(() => 
        ParrallelEnumerable.Range(start, count).COunt(n => 
            Enumerable.Range(2, (int)Math.Sqrt(n) - 1).All(i => n % i > 0)));
}
```

Here the `async` modifier tells the compiler to treat await as a keyword rather than an identifier should any ambiguity arise within that method. This insures that the code written prior to C# 5.0 that might use await as an identifier still compiles without error. The async modifier can be applied only to methods and lambda expressions that return void or `Task`/`Task<TResult>`.

Upon encountering the `await` expression, execution (normally) returns to the caller - rather like with `yeild return` in an itterator. But before returning, the runtime attaches a continuation to the awaited task, ensuring that when the task completes, execution jumps back into the method an continues where it left off. I suppose you could write the above method showing what the compiler translates it to as

```
void DisplayPrimesCount()
{
    var awaiter = GetPrimesCountAsync(2, 100000).GetAwaiter();
    awaiter.OnCompleted(() =>
    {
        int result = awaiter.GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    });
}
```

I hope this helps.

---

Edit. so to avoid the task blocking (it is hard to tell what your case is as you have posted no code), you need to bring the `async` process you want to create 'up a level'

```
private async Task<bool> TestAsync()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        // Do stuff non-blocking.            
        return true;
    }).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext:false);
}
```

`TestAsync` here will be able to complete by executing its "return" statement on a thread pool thread instead of the UI context. This will return to the caller immediately but note however, if you continue to use `Task.Result`, then any exceptions get wrapped in an `AggregateException` which you will have to deal with accordingly.

A good explanation can be found [on MSDN here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/269172a3-adb9-4b5e-9ac1-8b67ff920177/). I would recomend learning about C# 4.0 Tasks before getting into `async`/`await` as it will give you a better understanding of concurrency.

Comment: I am understand correctly the article, the problem is that if I use the Tas.Run, I create a new thread, and this use more resources so the objetive is not to use a new thread for the async methods. The problem is, by the moment, I don't know how to implment the async method without task.Run and not to block the UI. The article use the TaskCompletionSource, that does not create a new thread, But I don´t know hot to use it in the correct way.

Comment: See edit for a bit more clarification.

Comment: Sounds like you're misunderstanding the concept of running something "async", because it essentially always involves a second thread. If you don't feel comfortable with creating/dropping additional threads, you could create one additional thread that will wait for things to process (no busy loop!), essentially reusing its resources. Downside is, you can only process one async request per run, but it will work.

Comment: @Mario: "essentially always involves a second thread." I would disagree with that statement. Only asynchronous code needs another thread; all other asynchronous operations (I/O, timers, events) do not.

Comment: until now, I have followed the way that you say in your las example. In which yo put "Do stuff non-blocking" I use a sync method, because it could be complex code and is more readable. But in this way, is to wrap a sync method in a task to create my async method. is that what the author of the article try to avoid?

Comment: @StephenCleary: Yes, okay - but it really depends on the implementation and how asynchronous you'd like it to be (and how it's implemented).